# Where is the heroku database?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, heroku

I am trying to host my php application over heroku cloud services. This is my first ever try with any GIT client; following the procedure as defined in heroku documentation, I am done with pushing my files to the repo.

But now one place where I am totally lost is **where is the heoku database, how can I configure it?**

I went through `myapp>resources` where it tells the 5mb of database can be used for free, the only clickable link there is the `5mb` label but even that is not taking me anywhere.

But where is the control panel of that database, where I can edit and use sql to configure my database? Finds its name, username etc. (may be an interface like *phpmyadmin*)?

Kindly guide me through this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "control panel" for the Heroku database. As for "where is it", there is a `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` environment variable of the form:

```
$ heroku config | grep DATABASE
SHARED_DATABASE_URL   => postgres://username:password@host:port/database_name
```

In your PHP code, you can get this like so:

```
$database_url = getenv('SHARED_DATABASE_URL');
```

You may need to do some parsing of that URL to get it into a format that your PHP database API needs (it's been a while since I wrote any PHP).

As for "how do I configure my database", either from the command line, e.g.

```
$ heroku run php
```

or, assuming your code has some ORM-y features, invoking that to set up the database schema, or using heroku's `db:push` command, e.g.:

```
$ heroku db:push [URL_TO_MY_LOCAL_SOURCE_DATABASE]
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something like phpmyadmin for heroku databases, and I found the Adminium add-on, which works in a similar way.

Much easier than console.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will automatically setup your access to the database.

You may use taps to push and pull data betweeen your development machine and heroku. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Alternateively, you may use pgbackup - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Heroku recommends pgbackup as the most complete way of handling your database data (as described on the taps page).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you push something to Heroku it is the production side of the application, so it has a separate database that uses the same schema that you have designed once it has been migrated over.
So all your data will need re-entering through the Heroku App which can be found at:
'app name'.herokuapp.com